# How do we prove that Peano Arithmetic is effectively generated?

Tags: arithmetic, computability

I'm trying to understand what 'effectively generated' theory means. Wikipedia says that it means that its set of theorems form a 'recursively enumerable' set, which I found equally confusing.

As an example how would one prove that Peano Arithmetic is effectively generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit easier to think about *recursive*, rather than recursively enumerable, axiom sets (at least at first). A set of sentences $S$ is recursive iff, informally, we have an algorithm to tell what sentences are in $S$ and what sentences are not in $S$. This is a desirable property for a theory to have: we shouldn't, for example, be uncertain as to whether a given sentence is actually an axiom of PA!

A theory $T$ is recursively axiomatizable if it has *some* axiomatization which is recursive - remember that a given theory can be axiomatized in many different ways in general, and some axiomatizations might be pointlessly complicated (there's no rule that we can't have redundant axioms, for example).

*(It's worth noting that the recursively axiomatizable theories are exactly the recursively enumerably axiomatizable theories, even though the latter seems a priori a broader class; this is [due to Craig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig%27s_theorem).)*

In the specific case of PA, we have a *standard axiomatization*, consisting of (i) the ordered semiring axioms (of which there are only finitely many) and (ii) the induction *scheme* (which has infinitely many instances). To decide whether a given sentence $\varphi$ is an axiom of PA, we must check:

- **Is $\varphi$ one of the ordered semiring axioms?** Since there are only finitely many of those, this is something we can just do.
- **If not, is $\varphi$ an instance of the induction scheme?** Since there are infinitely many instances, we can't just check them one by one. Instead, we check whether $\varphi$ has a specific form: is there some formula $\psi(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $\varphi$ literally is the sentence $$Ind_\psi:\quad\forall x_1,...,x_n(\psi(0,x_1,...,x_n)\wedge\forall y(\psi(y,x_1,...,x_n)\rightarrow\psi(y+1,x_1,...,x_n))\implies\forall y(\psi(y,x_1,...,x_n)))?$$ The point here is that (i) there are only finitely many possible $\psi$s we need to check (namely, the formulas shorter than $\varphi$) and (ii) the map $\psi\mapsto Ind_\psi$ is recursive. So this is in fact something we can do: check, for each $\psi$ shorter than $\varphi$, whether $\varphi$ is the sentence $Ind_\psi$.

  - An important point to keep in mind here is that when I say that one sentence is/isn't another, I'm talking about literal same-ness: "$x=x$" and "$x=x\wedge x=x$" are *not* the same formula, even though they're obviously equivalent.

The above procedure is completely algorithmic: it gives us a way to tell whether a sentence is one of the PA axioms. Now this obviously isn't a formal proof, but rather a "proof by Church's thesis;" however it isn't hard to turn it completely formal (if deeply tedious).

Answer (score 3):

Usually one would appeal to a general theorem:

> Let $T$ be a theory. If the *axioms* of $T$ form a decidable set (that is, the theory is *recursively axiomatized*), then the set of *theorems* of $T$ is recursively enumerable.

Since it ought to be easy to see that the set of *axioms* of PA is decidable, the result follows.

The theorem above is easy enough to prove once you have decided on a definition for "recursively enumerable". Unfortunately there are several possible definitions of that, which are equivalent but not *obviously* so -- but a major part of learning recursion theory is to familiarize oneself deeply with the fact that they're equivalent.

For this purpose it will be convenient to use the definition that a set is r.e. if it is the range of a partial computable function. Namely, here is pseudocode for a partial computable function whose range is the theorems of $T$:

- Interpret the input as a string of symbols (using your favorite coding).
- Check whether this string of symbols is a valid proof (using your favorite proof system). This amounts to checking whether it is a list of wffs, and whether each wff in the list is either an axiom (we're assuming we can decide that!) or the conclusion of a rule of inference applied to something earlier in the list (just try all combinations; there are finitely many of them).
- If the string of symbols *is* a valid proof, then print the conclusion of the proof.
- Otherwise, loop forever.